# how to fix Failed to load FirebaseOptions from resource. Check that you have defined values.xml

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, hybrid-mobile-app

```
E/flutter ( 6571): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(java.lang.Exception: Failed to load FirebaseOptions from resource. Check that you have defined values.xml correctly., Exception, Cause: null, Stacktrace: java.lang.Exception: Failed to load FirebaseOptions from resource. Check that you have defined values.xml correctly.
```

E/flutter ( 6571):  at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.lambda$optionsFromResource$4$io-flutter-plugins-firebase-core-FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin(FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java:207)
E/flutter ( 6571):  at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.run(Unknown Source:4)
E/flutter ( 6571):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
E/flutter ( 6571):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
E/flutter ( 6571):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
E/flutter ( 6571): , null)
E/flutter ( 6571): #0      FirebaseCoreHostApi.optionsFromResource (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:242:7)
E/flutter ( 6571): 
E/flutter ( 6571): #1      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:89:25)
E/flutter ( 6571): 
E/flutter ( 6571): #2      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:43:31)

error throws right after calling   `await Firebase.initializeApp();`

its happening after removing **imperative apply of Flutter's Gradle plugins** which is deprecated.
ie. after migrate to the new, declarative apply issue started.
checked by creating new project also facing same issue
[`settings.gradle` file snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnGbk.png)

*app building for ios and android not web
env:
`firebase_core: ^2.27.1`
[flutter doctor result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwFva.png)

any help to fix this issue would be appreciated.
thankz

Answer (score 10):

after a bit research and struggle i found that after passing `options` its working ,

```
 await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: FirebaseOptions(
    apiKey: 'key',
    appId: 'id',
    messagingSenderId: 'sendid',
    projectId: 'myapp',
    storageBucket: 'myapp-b9yt18.appspot.com',
  )
    );
```

created new app, and configured it with cli mode it will generate the options file for all platforms.
Just add `google-services.json` won't be enough from flutte 3.19 it seems

[firebase cli config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli?hl=en&authuser=0#install_the_firebase_cli)

Good luck.

once the files are generated your firebaseinit code should look like this
options are applied through CLI geneteated options file according to platform

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform
    );
```

consider an upvote if it helps :)